# I would like to save Image as path to sqlite and retrieve it then show on ImageView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageUri = data.getData();
    showToast(imageUri.getPath());
```

1. Am I correct about to get the Image Path shown on the Toast?

Here is another one to show on ImageView:

```
public void setIvImg(String path) {
    this.ivImg.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
}
```

2. Am I correct about showing the image on ImageView?

**PS: I already use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.**

Comment: I guess you need describe more details about your question.I guess nobody can understand what's real problem .

Comment: Storing an image path is a bad idea..because if the image is deleted from memory then it won't work. Instead you should convert image into BLOB and then save it to database. Same thing is happening in Contact app.

Comment: did you try testing it?

Comment: I got the answer. thanks everyone

Comment: @SurenderKumar if/when an image reaches about 2M using standard Android Cursor based retrieval it becomes impossible to retrieve the image because a Cursor Windows is restricted to 2M. As such generally saying store images may result in an App crashing.Same would apply for other large data. So the underlying data (image) should be saved as a file and the path saved in the DB (if images avg 100k then saving as a Blob can be more efficient)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that stores the paths in the Database (named itdb) in the table named image_path that has two columns per row **_id** (an alias of the **rowid**, so uniquely identifies a row as a long) and **image_path** which is used for the actual path to the image file.

In this example the images (a few JPG's) have been dropped into the assets folder for simplicity (no need for permissions).

The App when it starts looks at the assets and stores asset file paths that contain .JPG (not anything fancy here). The loadImagePaths method does this.

- Note as the **image_path** column has been defined with the UNIQUE constraint existing images will be ignored (although an exception will be written to the log).

The handleListView will then extract the rows from the table via a Cursor which is the source data for the SimpleCursorAdapter that is attached to the ListView. Two listeners are set :-

- one for **onItemClick**, which populates the ImageView.
- the other for **onItemLongClick** which will delete the entry from the database and then refresh the ListView. (rerunning the App will add any deleted image paths to the database).

With 4 files :-

- MyEnlighten20180927_Consumption.JPG
- MyEnlighten20180927_Overview.JPG
- MyEnlighten20180927_Production.JPG
- MyEnlighten20180927_ProductionGridView.JPG

The the App looks like, when started (no item has been clicked) :-

[image]

Clicking an item results in the image being displayed e.g. :-

[image]

The App consists of 3 components, the layout **activity_main.xml**, the DatabaseHelper **DatabaseHelper.java** and the Activity **MainActivity.java**

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFAAAAFF"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFAAFFAA"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "itdb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBNAME = "image_path";
    public static final String IMAGEPATH_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String IMAGEPATH_COL_PATH = "image_path";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crt_imagepath_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                IMAGEPATH_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                IMAGEPATH_COL_PATH + " TEXT UNIQUE" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_imagepath_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addImagePath(String imagePath) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(IMAGEPATH_COL_PATH,imagePath);
        return mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public int deleteImagePathById(long id) {
        String whereclause = IMAGEPATH_COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        return mDB.delete(TBNAME,whereclause,whereargs);
    }

    public Cursor getImageList() {
        return mDB.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mAssetList;
    String mPath = "" ;
    String mImageExtension = ".JPG";
    ListView mLV;
    ImageView mIV;

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLV = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mIV = this.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        loadImagePaths();
        handleListView();
    }

    /**
     * Handle displaying the ListView, initialising it or refreshing it
     *
     * When initialising the
     */
    private void handleListView() {
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getImageList();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCsr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHelper.IMAGEPATH_COL_PATH},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mLV.setAdapter(mSCA);
            mLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    displayImage(mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.IMAGEPATH_COL_PATH)));
                }
            });
            mLV.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    mDBHlpr.deleteImagePathById(l);
                    handleListView(); // Refresh Listview as underlying image path has been deleted
                    return true; // indicate event has been handled
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mCsr.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void displayImage(String imagepath) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = this.getResources().getAssets().open(imagepath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mIV.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    private void loadImagePaths() {
        try {
            mAssetList = this.getAssets().list(mPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        for (String s: mAssetList) {
            if (s.contains(mImageExtension)) {
                mDBHlpr.addImagePath(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This demonstrates the basics of using images with their paths stored in the database.

- Note if using the above then some files with a JPG extension would have to be copied into the assets folder (unless the code is changed to handle a different location).